# jmeter extract multiple array from xml

Tags: xml-parsing, jmeter

HTTP GET, retrive values from an xml
and than I need to call a PUT many times as the number of element with some values I got from the first GET.

I have an xml for example

```
<root>
<element>
<valId>1111</valId>
<valName>Name</valName>
</element>
<element>
<valId>1111</valId>
<valName>Name</valName>
</element>
....
</root>
```

So I have:
HTTP GET: retrive an xml
xpath extractor 1 for valsId
xpath extractor 2 for valsName
Now I have two array with multiple values in valId and valName, I can access to them with valsId_1, valsId_2, etc
Then I have a foreach controller in input I have valsId and output the current value myId.
as child of foreach controller I have my http PUT where I use myId but I don't know how to get the current value of valsName.

In my opinion for this kind of problem there two way:
1 extract the values in array, as I did
2 extract a part of xml and than process it everytime in a for

I hope you understand what I meant with my problem.
Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

For handling second variable "valsName" just place below code

> ${__BeanShell(vars.get("valsName_"+${__counter(TRUE,page)}))}

at the position of Name

`<valName>Name</valName>`

it'll resolve your problem.